# Firebase Hosting not showing localized build

Tags: angular, firebase, internationalization, firebase-hosting

I want to have English as default under http://myapp.com/en/ and Japanese under http://myapp.com/ja/.
But both are showing in English (the default). I have changed so that it should do rewrite to the dorrect language folder in the firebase.json file, also added the i18n root to the same as where the language folders are (see below).

I have tested in my local computer with serve and the translation work but not after prod (firebase) deploy.

In my angular.json file it looks like this.

```
 "i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": {
      "code": "en",
      "baseHref": "en"
    },
    "locales": {
      "ja": {
        "translation": "src/locale/messages.ja.xlf",
        "baseHref": "ja"
      }
    }
  },
```

Locally it works well when I do ng serve. or ng serve --configuration="ja". My serve looks like this in angular.json.

```
    "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
      },
      "ja": {
        "browserTarget": "myapp:build:ja"
      }
    }
  },
```

Now when I do build I do this.
ng build --prod --localize
I tried with aot=disabled to see if it made any difference, it did not.

build looks like this from angular.json.

```
"build": {
    "localize": true,
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
      "index": "src/index.html",
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "aot": true,
      "assets": [
        "src/favicon.ico",
        "src/assets"
      ],
      "styles": [
        "src/styles.css",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]
    },
    "configurations": {
      "ja": {
        "localize": [
          "ja"
        ]
      },
      "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": false,
        "budgets": [
          {
            "type": "initial",
            "maximumWarning": "2mb",
            "maximumError": "5mb"
          },
          {
            "type": "anyComponentStyle",
            "maximumWarning": "6kb",
            "maximumError": "10kb"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Now my firebase.json looks like this:

```
    {
    "hosting": {
      "public": "./dist/myapp",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/ja/**",
          "destination": "/ja/index.html"
        },
        {
          "source": "/en/**",
          "destination": "/en/index.html"
        }
      ],
      "i18n": {
        "root": "/"
      }
    }
  }
```

So I can visit the app at both /en/ and /ja/ but ja is not translating. Any pointers on what I am doing wrong more than I head recently that you should have your localize folder in a separate folder and the root folder? With these settings I feel like it should work but something is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing

```
"baseHref": "en"
```

and

```
"baseHref": "ja"
```

from the angular.json file under i18n made it work! I have missunderstood what baseHref does!